# mobile responsive not working when rotated landscape

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

So our website is in its last stages before we make it live, however we have just noticed when we were checking mobile responsive everything was working fine, until we rotated the mobile to landscape view and it displayed the same styles as on a desktop and the responsive media wearies weren't working! 
  our responsive code is as follows:

```css
@media screen and (max-width:600px){
.stats{
    display:none;
}
}
```

can anyone help please?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/#tablet-queries

media queries for different devices.

Comment: In landscape screen is bigger than 600px so you need another media query.

Comment: you need to write 767px to mobile devices and 768 to 1200 for tablets

Comment: What is the device you are testing on? Chances are the width in landscape is greater than 600px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

between head tags so you can get correct width from mobile devices (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) and change your media query as

```
@media screen and (max-width:767px){
  .stats{
    display:none;
  }
}
```

for mobile devices (phones)

Answer (score 3):

A landscape device ratio is bigger than 600px. If you use chrome, dev tools, when re sizing the viewport it shows you exactly the amount of pixels which is visible.

Off the top off my head, i would say you need to change your media query to;

```
@media screen and (max-width:787px){
.stats{
   display:none;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add orientation brother.

```css
@media (orientation: landscape) {
  /* Your landscape-specific styles here */
}
```